# CKEDITOR mathjax formula not show completely

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-admin, mathjax

I am using ckeditor with mathjax plugin to type formula. However the formula is not displayed completely. The end part of the formula is missing. I guess its width is not enough.

[image]

This is html code that ckeditor generates:

```
<span class="math-tex">\(\left[ {{{ - \pi } \over 2};\,{{3\pi } \over 2}} \right]\)</span>
```

If I use mathjax library to display this code, it shows correctly.

[image]

Only on ckeditor, it has the issue. 
Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded mathjax to version 2.2. It displays correctly now.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
         'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            # 'devtools',
            'mathjax',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
```